# iOS. Replace method call with directives?

Tags: ios, nsstring, preprocessor, directive

it is just an example:

```
#define Item1 @"1"
#define Item2 @"2"
...
#define Item10 @"10"

#define GeneralItem Item1

- (NSString *)generalItemID {

  if ([GeneralItem isEqualToString:Item1]) {

    return @"...";
  }
  if ([GeneralItem isEqualToString:Item2]) {

    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Is it possible to replace this code with another one without writing of custom methods/functions?

This code looks awful but it is because of several versions of the same application.

**UPDATED**

I want to replace `generalItemID` method with something like this:

`#define GeneralItemID ...`

which returns the same result

Comment: i'm not quite understand what are you doing, why, and what would you like to achieve. I think you should detail your question

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope it is clear for you now

Answer (score 0):

You can create a preprocessor macro for the method above with two approaches. If you don't need to call this on a specific instance of GeneralItem, then you can make the generalItemID method a class method, and then can use the following macro:

```
#define GeneralItemID [GeneralItem generalItemID]
```

However, I'm guessing that you will need to call this on a specific instance, and so you can use the following macro:

```
#define GeneralItemID(o) [o generalItemID]
```

Which would be used as follows:

```
GeneralItem *genItem = [GeneralItem alloc] init];

NSString *itemID = GeneralItemID(genItem);
```

This should do what you are asking for.  However, based on some of your explanation this may not be the approach that you are looking for at all.  If you need to implement the same functionality into multiple objects, then consider making the rest of your objects subclasses of GeneralItem, and they will inherit the method 'generalItemID'.

Comment: I didn't mean this. You still have the same method, and use #define to create its synonim only.

Answer (score 0):

My current temp solution is the following:

```
typedef enum {
  Item1,
  Item2,
  ...
  Item10
} Item;

#define GeneralItem Item1

@interface SomeClassWithConstants : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain readonly) NSString *item;

+ (SomeClassWithConstants *)sharedInstance; //singleton method

@end

@implementation

- (id)init {

  ...
  switch (GeneralItem) {

    case Item1:
    {
      item = @"1";
      break;
    }
    ...
  }
}

@end
```

This code use a singleton with settings instead of additional preprocessor directive. But at least it guarantees that checking of `GeneralItem` value will be performed only once.